What do Detect Magic and Identify reveal about the target of a "basic" Wish?
Suppose I cast wish, duplicating the effect of sympathy, targeting a rock. If someone later casts detect magic, what school of magic would they detect on the rock (e.g. Conjuration or Enchantment)? If they cast identify on the rock, what will will it report about the spell affecting the rock (e.g. wish or sympathy)?

Does this answer your question? When using wish to replicate a spell, what school of magic does it count as? I can't see the answer for Identify being any different than it is for Detect Magic.

@ShadowRanger Yep, that'll do it. Not sure why that one didn't come up in my own search for duplicates.
